# Adding an arrow function to input field results an error

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Here is a React class I'm working on:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ExpenseForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        title: ''
    };

    onTitleChange = (e) => {
        const title = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({title}));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='title'
                        value={this.state.title}
                        onChange={(e) => this.setState(() => ({title: e.target.value}))}
                        required autoFocus/>
                    <textarea placeholder='Add a note for your expense'/>
                    <input type='number' placeholder='amount' required/>
                    <input type='submit' value='Add Expense'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` when executing `onChange`.

But when I restructure inner js of `onChange` into a separate function `onTitleChange` and calling that function: `onChange={this.onTitleChange}`, it works perfectly. What could be the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you assigned onchange event as `onChange={(e) => this.setState(() => ({title: e.target.value}))}`, here `e.target.value` will not work, because its inside the `setState()` scope.

On expanding your function, we will get

```
function(e){
   this.setState(function(){
     return {
       title: e.target.value
     }
   })
}
```

Here there is no `e` in function inside `setSate()`, so `e.target.value` will be error;

Since you dont want to compare with previous value and only need to set the value to title, you can use like

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({title: e.target.value})}
```

There is no need for an extra function inside `setState`

Answer (score 2):

I would guess, that your parameter e is not known in the inner arrow function.
You could write it like this:

```
<input
  type='text'
  placeholder='title'
  value={this.state.title}
  onChange={e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
  required
  autoFocus
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of React is utilizing [event pooling](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling) and setState is a function executed in asynchronous context, so you observe them as nulls in the asynchronous `setState` callback.

You need to either persist event using `e.persist()` or save the value of `event` to variable, as in your method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use arrow function inside `setstate`.

change
`onChange={(e) => this.setState(() => ({title: e.target.value}))}`

to:
`onChange={(e) => this.setState({title: e.target.value})}`

Comment: Use arrow function inside `setState` when you need to access previous state